# How do I access the current route on a Next.JS custom 404 page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next-router

I have a custom 404 page in my Next.JS app (404.js). On the page, I'd like to display a message like `The route <strong>/not-a-route</strong> does not exist`, however when using Next.js's `useRouter()` and `router.pathname`, the router thinks I'm on `/404` and instead displays `The route <strong>/404</strong> does not exist`. How do I access the actual route I'm on in a custom 404 page?

```js
export const NotFound: React.FC = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  console.log(router.pathname) // prints /404
  return (
    <Layout title='Oops! Something went wrong!'>
      <div className={styles.container}>
        <h1>Oops! Something went wrong!</h1>
          <p>
            The route <strong>{router.pathname}</strong> does not exist.
          </p>
      </div>
    </Layout>
  );
};
```

Comment: Well you are actually on `/404`. Can you show us where do you do the redirect? You can pass the route name as `props` to the `404 page `

Comment: @SinanYaman if the user accidentally navigates to `/abouts` instead of `/about`, the text on the page currently displays `/404` even though the browser URL is still `/abouts` - this is the scenario I'm currently trying to account for; it's not caused by a dodgy redirect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access the `redirected route` as `router.asPath`. Try:

```
import {useRouter} from 'next/router'
export const NotFound: React.FC = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  console.log(router.asPath)
  return (
    <Layout title='Oops! Something went wrong!'>
      <div className={styles.container}>
        <h1>Oops! Something went wrong!</h1>
          <p>
            The route <strong>{router.asPath}</strong> does not exist.
          </p>
      </div>
    </Layout>
  );
};
```

Comment: Works, but only client side. Server result will be `asPath: "/404"` - that will result in a warning: "...did not match. Server ..."

Answer (score 2):

You can access the original route by accessing `router.asPath`, where `router` is returned from `useRouter()` hook. Beware though, if you don't specify `getStaticProps`, `router.asPath` will return `"/404"` on server side, causing hydration error.

So to make use of `router.asPath` you will have to create `getStaticProps` function that doesn't return anything

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

import type { GetStaticProps } from 'next';

type Props = Record<string, never>;

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps<Props> = () => {
  return { props: {} };
};

export default function PageNotFound() {
  const router = useRouter();

  return (
    <p>
      The requested page <strong>{router.asPath}</strong> could not be found.
    </p>
  );
}
```

Comment: This seems to be a good solution. It should be the accepted answer rather than the other.

Answer (score 1):

Old question but just adding onto this if you're using Next.js 13

Instead of using `router.asPath`, you need to import `usePathname` from `next/navigation`

Eg.

```
'use client';

import { usePathname } from 'next/navigation';

const NotFoundPage = (): JSX.Element => {
    return (
        <div>
           {usePathname()} not found
        </div>
    );
};

export default NotFoundPage;
```